# Can a python script write into itself

Tags: python

I am creating a simple AI program in Python 2.7 and  i was going to make it be able to learn.  Is there any way to have it so the script could edit itself,  like adding a answer to a question into it's own code, in a certain spot in the code.

thank-you in advance guys!

Comment: thats not how you get a programm to "learn", use a database and write new answers or whatever in there, but not in the code

Comment: You may be able to modify the script, but that's not what you want to do. Use a database instead.

Comment: Ok, how would i create a database?  This is only my 3rd day learning python 2.7 so i have no idea what that is.

Comment: For a start, you could look for SQLite.

Comment: Easy to do when using a database. But it will be quite a lot effort if you plan to write into the source file.

Comment: While self-modifying code is possible, it's generally regarded as something to avoid. In particular, it's nasty to debug. A clean separation of code and data is preferred.

Comment: I don't think an AI program is the best choice to start learning Python!

Comment: @CalderHutchins start with the basics mate and you'll never fall, those database stuff are way too complicated if you have just started using python.

Comment: @don and K DawG, i like a challenge :)

Comment: What about a [pickle](http://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingPickle)?

Comment: Have a look at this complete project: https://github.com/rouge8/20questions

Answer (score 9):

When a Python interpreter is invoked on a script, it is parses and transforms it into byte-code.. this leaves a .pyc file which is actually what executed.

A script could write into itself but that would not cause parsing to restart.

Comment: ok, thank-you for that bit of information.

Comment: There is an option to evaluate and execute dynamically generated code via the AST module (abstract syntax tree) but that may not be a great option. How about building an engine that consumes data?

Answer (score 4):

You could open the file containing the code using:

```
module = __import__(__name__)
with open(module.__file__) as f:
    print f.read()
```

Although it is not recommended to dynamically alter the source code.